# Spring.NET, NHibernate and WCF: Session Management

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, session, spring.net

I know that this issue has been discussed but all answers seem to be quite outdated (back in 2008).

I have a perfectly well configured application architecture with Spring.NET DI and transaction management and NHibernate. Session management works well within my integration tests.

But: what is the best way to handle the NHibernate session within WCF?

Are there any new concepts, frameworks?

Best
Max

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented session/transaction management in WCF with the help of [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx). It allows you to react on events like Begin/End reqest.

I have wrote a [blog post](http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/wcf-nhibernate-session-transaction.html) about it. Its in russian, but code is in c# :). I hope it will help you.

Also you can have a look at [sharp architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net). They implemented session/transaction management for both mvc and wcf.